No more "Event Log" window in "Android Studio" Koala for Mac
I'm new with "Android Studio" Koala and I'm not finding the "Event Log" window I was used to. It should have an item "Event Log" in the View / Tool Windows menu somewhere under the "Device Manager" item, but no "Event Log" item. Is it a configuration problem? So how can I fix it? Below a screen capture of my View / Tool Windows menu 

I was using event log to locate app bundle. I am using Notifications now.
